# what is php regex for check if upload file name have german umlauts?

Tags: php, regex

what is php regex for check if upload file name have german umlauts?
file name :  Screenshot_Erdös.png

i tried below but not working

```
if ( preg_match('(?<![äöüÄÖÜß\w])([äöüÄÖÜß\w]+)(?![äöüÄÖÜß\w])', $file_name )){
        $file['error'] = __( "WARNING: Invalid file name. German umlauts are not allowed.", 'wp-file' );
    }
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Describe your problem, post your best try and explain in detail where you are stuck.

Comment: @nvoigt please check my edited question and help me. i already searched in google and stackoverflow but nothing to work

Comment: Changed answer try it once more and check the value of $file_name

Comment: Why do you want to ban filenames with umlauts?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to produce an **"a with umlaut (or diaeresis)"** with UNICODE:

- the *"readymade"* character: codepoint **U+00E4   `ä`    LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS**
- the combination of two codepoints the **U+0061    `a`    LATIN SMALL LETTER A**), followed by  **U+0308   `̈`   COMBINING DIAERESIS**

All other vowels **"e i o u"** and the **"y"** too are in the same situation: there are these two ways to produce them.

To deal with this state of affairs, you can simply consider the two possibilities in your pattern, but you can also use the [Normalizer from intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) to convert the string to NFC before.

---

Other thing to take in account, when you have to deal with multibyte characters (that is the case in UTF-8 for accented characters), you need to inform the regex engine, otherwise this one will read the subject string and the pattern byte by byte instead of codepoint by codepoint.

Consider this character class: `[ä]` (with the *"readymade"* small A with diaeresis). **ä** is encoded with two bytes in UTF-8: C3 A4.
That means that by default a pattern with this character class will succeed if one of these two byte is found in the subject string. But that doesn't mean that the subject string contains **ä**:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~[ä]~', '↤')); // int(1)
```

This pattern succeeds because **U+21A4    `↤`   LEFTWARDS ARROW FROM BAR** is encoded with the bytes E2 86 A4 and the byte A4 is found.

To inform the regex engine that the strings (the pattern and the subject) have to be read codepoint by codepoint, you can start the pattern like that:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~(*UTF8)[ä]~', '↤')); // int(0)
```

or use the u modifier:

```
var_dump(preg_match('~[ä]~u', '↤')); // int(0)
```

---

To conclude, a pattern to match a diaeresis can be written like that:

```
preg_match('~[äëïöüÿ\N{U+00A8}\N{U+0308}]~ui', $subject)
```

or

```
preg_match('~[äëïöüÿ\N{U+00A8}]|[aeiouy]\N{U+0308}~ui', $subject)
```

where `\N{U+0308}` stands for the combining diaeresis and `\N{U+00A8}` for the diaeresis alone. `äëïöüÿ` are *"readymade"* characters from the UNICODE block U+0080 -> U+00FF Latin-1 supplement. Uppercase letters are taken in account with the i modifier.

or like that:

```
preg_match('~(*UTF8)[äëïöüÿ\N{U+00A8}\N{U+0308}]~i', $subject)
```

or with a NFC normalized string:

```
preg_match('~[äëïöüÿ\N{U+00A8}]~ui', normalizer_normalize($subject))
```

Comment: The problem seems to be something else!! Nothing worked for him.

Comment: @AliJavaheri: One question = One problem, it's SO. If there's a problem elsewhere, it's out of the scope of the question, and clearly the code posted in the question doesn't make the job. My answer covers the question asked, nothing else. One problem at a time.

Comment: I know you are more experienced than me. I just said i tried it didn't work. But you are right about it

Comment: @AliJavaheri: you said "Nothing worked for him". No, your original answer (before your edit) was wrong for a reason explained in my answer: "sample_640×426.jpeg" contains the character "U+00D7 × MULTIPLICATION SIGN" encoded with C3 97 in UTF8 and the byte C3 is used for the Ä too (and all other characters with a diaeresis). Your edit doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: preg_match('~(*UTF8)[äëïöüÿ\N{U+00A8}\N{U+0308}]~i', $subject) is working for me. thanks

Comment: i also used this regex for jquery validation. but not working. need different regex for jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if (preg_match('/[äöüÄÖÜß]/', $file_name)) {
    $file['error'] = __("WARNING: Invalid file name. German umlauts are not allowed.", 'wp-file');
}
```

Comment: OK i used above for sample_640×426.jpeg file name but it return german umlauts error. But sample_640×426.jpeg file not have german umlauts. Please check for this file name.